scraping all apps from a certain category in google play store using google-play-scraper
I am using Google Play Scraper (https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper) to scrape apps from the google play store. I'd like to scrape all apps in a certain category (e.g. all apps under the "health and fitness" category. But it seems like you have to further restrict by "collections" into top paid, free, and grossing. This limits the results to just these groups. Is there a way to bypass this to extract all apps?
I tried extracting all apps from all three of these collections, but the results for one category were around ~600 apps which is definitely an underestimate of the total number of apps in this category.
